# Custom method with NSArray as input

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, uiscrollview, nsarray

I'm trying to create an UIScrollview starting from an NSArray.
The problem is that when I write the method everything is fine but then when I call that method in my NSArray I get this message: `no visible @interface for NSArray declares the selector 'createScrollView'`, like xcode doesn't see implementation.
I've tried also with a very stupid method, like

```
-(int)countData:(NSArray *)array {
return [array count];
}
```

but when I call `[myArray countData];` I get that array.
I think I miss something stupid, can you help me? thank you

edit: my current code below:

```
-(UIScrollView *)createModalView:(NSArray *)dataArray
{
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.count; i++)
{
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.size = scrollView.frame.size;
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

    CDOPageDescription *page = nil;
    page = [dataArray objectAtIndex:i];

    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * i, 0, 200, 40)];
    UILabel *urlLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * i, 40, 200, 40)];
    UILabel *sectionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * i, 80, 200, 40)];
    titleLabel.text = page.title;
    urlLabel.text = page.url;
    sectionLabel.text = page.sectionTitle;

    [scrollView addSubview:titleLabel];
    [scrollView addSubview:urlLabel];
    [scrollView addSubview:sectionLabel];

    scrollView.contentSize =  CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * dataArray.count, scrollView.frame.size.height);
}

return scrollView;
```

}

Comment: ARE you sure **array** is `NSArray` not `NSMutableArray` ?

Comment: First of all, it doesn't seem right to add instance method to `NSArray` that would initialise `UIScrollview`. Anyway, we need to see the code to understand why it isn't working for you.

Comment: NSArray doesn't have a method called "createScrollView".  Unless you created a "category" to provide one (which is probably beyond your skill level) the method must be in some other class.

Comment: @Carlo D, where do you put this code ? Where are you going to use it ? Do you have a header file with the method signature ?

Comment: yes i've it but without signature because it's called internally

Comment: createModelView

is a method that belongs in a view controller.  What .m file contains that method above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be trying to subclass NSArray or NSMutableArray. Those are "class clusters", which makes subclassing them quite difficult. (And makes it beyond your current skill level.) Plus it's the wrong thing to do in this case.

Secondly, an array should not have a scroll view property. An array is a data container class. It should not be tied to view objects. That is a very bad design.

Can you post the headers of your different classes and explain how they are supposed to relate to each other? You haven't shown enough context for us to figure out what you are doing.

You said:

> ...but when i call [myArray countData]; i get that array. I think i
>   miss something stupid, can you help me?

You have defined an instance method in some class (unspecified) that takes an array as a parameter, and returns a count.

Calling `[myArray countData]` does not make sense. That tries to send the `countData` message to the array. The array doesn't have a `countData` method, your class does. It should be

```
[self countData: myArray];
```

Which means "send the message `countData:` to myself, with a parameter of myArray".